# Application of Inclusion–exclusion principle in probability.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, reference-request

In class we have seen the Inclusion-exclusion principle in probability which say that for events $A_1,\cdots,A_n$ we have $$\mathbb{P}\biggl(\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i\biggr)  =\sum_{k=1}^n \left((-1)^{k-1}\sum_{\scriptstyle I\subset\{1,\ldots,n\}\atop\scriptstyle|I|=k} \mathbb{P}(\bigcap_{i\in I} A_i
)\right).
$$

> I know three beautiful applications : one of this is to *count* the number of onto functions, and the second, to count also the number of permutations without fixed points. The last one, my favorite, calculation of *Euler's* phi function.

I wonder if there is another **unexpected**, **powerful** application of this formula ?